# Each loop inside Case for Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to dynamically generate a case statement based on an array of values. For example let's say I have an array of ranges

`[1..3,4..6,7..20,21..38]`

and I want to write a dynamic case statement that returns the first number of whatever range

```
case n
  ranges.each do |r|
  when r
    r.first
  end
end
```

Is this possible, or will I have to find another way to do it (my actual code is more complex)?

Comment: Please show what you want to do (typically, input and output) rather than showing a code that you are not sure.

Comment: Instead of asking how to implement an attempted solution (dynamic code generation) you should ask about your actual problem. What is your code supposed to do? Maybe a `case` expression isn't the right tool in the first place. What do you mean by _"actual code is more complex"_? Describe your problem, please.

Comment: as @Stefan said, you could just do `ranges.find { |r| r.cover?(n) }&.first`

Answer (score 4):

If i get your question right, then you can forget `case` statement and do it using [detect](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html):

```
ary = [1..3, 4..6, 7..20, 21..38]

num = 15    # say

ary.detect { |sub_ary| sub_ary.include?(num) }
 => 7..20

ary.detect { |sub_ary| sub_ary.include?(num) }.first     # call `first` on result of above, which is a range, to get the first element.
 => 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Just out of curiosity:

```
number = 5
instance_eval [
  "case number",
  *ranges.map { |r| "when #{r} then (#{r}).first" },
  "end"
].join($/)
#⇒ 4
```

Comment: SO needs to support adding reactions. This one would get a :heart: :).

Comment: @JagdeepSingh like this: ❤?

Comment: @mudasobwa Why `*ranges` and not just `ranges`

Comment: @KartikeyTanna for explicity. Join hides the difference, but the proper array should not be nested.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to *#detect* (or *#find*) with *#include?* from [Jagdeep Singhs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50923303/3982562) you can also use the case equality operator ([`Range#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)). This operator is used by the case statement to compare the input value with the scenario's you're providing.

```
ranges.find { |range| range === n }.first
```

Keep in mind both *#detect* and *#find* return `nil` if no value can be found. This means you might want to use the safe navigation operator (`}&.first`) to prevent a no method exception of *#first* on `nil` if the value can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works, but is kind of pointless and thread unsafe:

```
def get_range(n)
  ranges = [1..3,4..6,7..20,21..38]

  case n
  when 3
    # special case
    199
  when ->(x) { @_get_range = ranges.find { |r| r.cover?(x) } }
    @_get_range.first
  else
    0
  end
ensure
  remove_instance_variable(:@_get_range) if instance_variable_defined?(:@_get_range)
end

get_range(3) # => 199
get_range(5) # => 4
get_range(50) # => 0
```

You could just do:

```
ranges.find { |r| r.cover?(n) }&.first || 0
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents..

```
ranges = [1..3,4..6,7..20,21..38]

num = 15

ranges.bsearch { |range| range.member? num }.begin
```